# Trouble with Nest API with windows XP / server 2003

Tags: ssl, firebase, nest-api

It seems that on june 11th, something changed on the Nest servers that prevent my [software](http://board.homeseer.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1218) to run properly on windows XP / windows server 2003.

I don't know what changed exactly but now none of the [TLS ciphers supported on win XP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  are accepted by the Nest servers

I tested all of them using curl:

```
curl -v --tlsv1 --ciphers EXP-RC4-MD5 https://firebase-apiserver05-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553/devices.json?auth=<my_token>
* About to connect() to firebase-apiserver05-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com port 9553 (#0)
*   Trying 54.196.73.38... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to firebase-apiserver05-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to firebase-apiserver05-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553
```

If someone from Nest is reading this, would it be possible to enable at least one of the cipher supported by win XP?

alternatively is there a way to have more ciphers supported by SChannel in win XP? For example AES128-SHA works with the Nest servers using curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP support ended in April last year (2014) and Windows Server 2003 support ends in a few days (14 July 2015). As a result they are limited to support older, and less secure protocols/ciphers.

I think you are out of luck with this one. If you had to I guess you could proxy the requests from legacy clients via another API that does support the less secure combinations of protocols/ciphers and then forward those requests to Nest. I wouldn't recommend it however.

Just make sure you consider any possible security ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a specific .net library for fire base I know one of other person to run into issues. So maybe check your fire base library or try a new one.